# All subgroups of a cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Find all subgroups of a cyclic group with 12 elements and show why the list is complete.

My intuition here is that the list of subgroups will have order of divisors of 12. So there's 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, and 12, thus there will be 6 subgroups. I am unclear how to explicitly find these subgroups though.

Comment: Have you encountered the theorem that all subgroups of a cyclic group are cyclic?

Comment: Two hints:  1.All subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic and 2. The order of a subgroup divides the order of the group (Lagrange's theorem)

Comment: We have done absolutely nothing with subgroups yet. All we have is the definition of a subgroup.

Comment: Think of the cyclic group as a clock with $n$ "hour" positions... here, $12$.  Lagrange's Theorem states the order of the order of the subgroup divides the order of the group (as D. Beec states).  So for $n = 2$ you have group elements at the "top" and "bottom" of the clock (the 12 o'clock and 6 o'clock positions).  For $n = 3$ you have 12 o'clock, 4 o'clock and 8 o'clock.  You do the rest...